# Installing Ubuntu upgrade side by side with old version

Tags: upgrade

I'd like to upgrade from Ubuntu 10.04 to 11.04, but keep the original Ubuntu 10.04. That is, instead of the new system overwriting the old one, I'd like it to offer Ubuntu 10.04 as a start up choice, whether on the boot level or on the Ubuntu user-profile level.

Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrading to 11.04 means getting rid of Ubuntu 10.04.

But you can have both versions side by side,this is can be easily done by installing Ubuntu 11.04 on a different partition.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I really don't want yet another partition on my machine.

Comment: @EplisonVector:Well, I guess there is no other option If you want to choose between the two versions from boot.So either you install Ubuntu 11.04 alongside 10.04 , or upgrade the system to 11.04 . Alternatively, In ubuntu 11.04 you can choose between unity and the original desktop(classic ubuntu desktop).